# How to load a model in a master controller on codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a master controller so that every other controllers on my app extend the master (MY_Controller).
My problem is how to make loading a model more abstract, let me show you the code to better explain.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    protected $model;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get($order_by)
    {
        $this->load->model($this->model);
        $query = $this->$this->model->get($order_by);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

I declare a protected variable `$model`  in the master controller so that on the extending controller i can asign it a value:

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->model = "home_model";
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $test = $this->get('id');
    }
}
```

The problem is that on MY_Controller i cant load the model

$this->$this->model->get();

i get the following error: `Message: Object of class Home could not be converted to string`

any help will be appreciated , thank you !

Comment: controller can't use as Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do not save the value you assign to protected global `$model` variable in a variable inside the function as such:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

  protected $model;

  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function get($order_by){
    $_model = $this->model // I added this line.
    $this->load->model($_model); // I modified this line.
    $query = $this->$_model->get($order_by);  // I modified this line.
    return $query;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$this->$this->model->get()` is your problem. If you want to use an object property (`$this->model`) inside a chain like this, you need to wrap it in braces: `$this->{$this->model}->get()`.